# Accepting payment in store without PCI

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'm looking for a way to accept payments inline in my store so users don't have to go off to paypal if they don't want to.

I've been reading about PCI compliance which sounds like a nightmare and quite expensive.

I've seen many sites doing this. One is here:

https://www.liquoricekids.co.uk/

On their payment page credit card details can be entered. It's a small shop so there's no way they're PCI compliant.

How can I accept payment in my shop?

I know this might get closed for being conversational but hopefully a kind soul can help me shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using a company that handles the PCI compliance for you.  You are right, PCI compliance can be a nightmare to deal with especially if you have limited resources to devote to becoming PCI compliant.

I would recommend using one of the many payment services.  Payment gateways like Recurly (which I work for), Braintree and Stripe have forms that can be embedded into your site for card collection.  This way your PCI liability is reduced due to the fact that the credit card number never hits your server.  They will also save the credit card to use again when needed.